# Using newer version of php on server

Tags: ubuntu, php, debian-wheezy, upgrade

What are my options if the version of PHP packaged with Debian Wheezy is too old and I want to run something newer? Besides switching to Ubuntu stable or running Debian Jessie (not great for production), is there a way to only install the new version of php and continue to receive package updates for it?

Answer (score 1):

Under ubuntu, Ondřej Surý maintains a PPA with always up-to-date PHP version with modules and extensions. Hope this will be usefull.

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just add the newest packagelist.

Edit the sourcelist:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the packages to the end of the list:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
```

Update the system:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Reference: http://www.dev-metal.com/setup-latest-version-php-5-5-debian-wheezy-7-07-1-fix-gpg-key-error/

Comment: You forgot to mention the actual website that publishes these newest PHP versions for Debian. It is http://www.dotdeb.org